# Locksmith error: Locksmith.LocksmithError.interactionNotAllowed

Tags: swift4, keychain

we're using Locksmith to save user data for Keychain. In our end everything works as it should but for some reason we receive crashes with the error `Locksmith.LocksmithError.interactionNotAllowed`.

Follows the code where the crash happen:

```
func updateUserAccessToken(forAccount account: String, token: String) {
    var userAccessToken = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount(userAccount: account) ?? [String: Any]()
    userAccessToken[“token”] = token
    try! Locksmith.updateData(data: userAccessToken, forUserAccount: account)
}
```

Why is the code above crashes for other users? 'til . now we can't replicate the said crash. Any help is very much appreciated.  Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
So we finally able to replicate this crash, and it's because we're accessing the keychain while the device is locked. I found out you can change the Keychain's "accessibility option" but I'm not sure how to do it in Locksmith. Anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that if you're using a *protocol base* approach changing the *accessibility option* is much more easier. But unfortunately our app doesn't use it. So what I did was I created an extension as follow:

```
extension Locksmith {
    fileprivate static func loadDataForUserAccount(userAccount: String,
                                                   inService service: String = LocksmithDefaultService,
                                                   accessibleOption: LocksmithAccessibleOption) -> [String: Any]? {
        struct ReadRequest: GenericPasswordSecureStorable, ReadableSecureStorable {
            let service: String
            let account: String
            var accessible: LocksmithAccessibleOption?
        }

        let request = ReadRequest(service: service, account: userAccount, accessible: accessibleOption)
        return request.readFromSecureStore()?.data
    }

    fileprivate static func updateData(data: [String: Any],
                                       forUserAccount userAccount: String,
                                       inService service: String = LocksmithDefaultService,
                                       accessibleOption: LocksmithAccessibleOption) throws {

        struct UpdateRequest: GenericPasswordSecureStorable, CreateableSecureStorable {
            let service: String
            let account: String
            let data: [String: Any]
            var accessible: LocksmithAccessibleOption?
        }

        let request = UpdateRequest(service: service, account: userAccount, data: data, accessible: accessibleOption)
        return try request.updateInSecureStore()
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** changing the *"accessibility option"* may loss your access to the data previously saved with the default *"accessibility option"*. If you need those data you may need to handle it separately.

Comment: could you explain a bit more on  `If you need those data you may need to handle it separately`

Comment: @LohithKorupolu you need to re-add them with the new accessibility option.