# Swift - Locksmith modify access level from whenUnlocked to afterFirstUnlock

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I have an app that tries to access the keychain items when the device is invoked in the background and locked. (thanks for the [help from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532038/swift-locksmith-loaddataforuseraccount-fails-sometimes)).

I am using **Locksmith** for managing my Keychain related operations, and now I would like to change the access level from `whenUnlocked` to `afterFirstUnlock`. For the class where I have the `update`, `load` and `delete` operations on Keychain, I have inherited from `SecureStorable` and set the accessible as below

```
public var accessible: LocksmithAccessibleOption? = {return .afterFirstUnlock}()
```

But the problem doesn't solve and I looked at the answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394209/locksmith-error-locksmith-locksmitherror-interactionnotallowed) with a **NOTE** that says

> changing the "accessibility option" may loss your access to the data
>   previously saved with the default "accessibility option". If you need
>   those data you may need to handle it separately.

What is the way I need to follow to implement this ***migration/update*** smoothly without impacting the users who are already using the app? Adding code of my class where I try to `update` and `load` data from keychain using `Locksmith`.

```
public final class MyAppSession: SecureStorable {

    public var accessible: LocksmithAccessibleOption? = {return .afterFirstUnlock}()

    public fileprivate(set) var isValid: Bool = false

    /**
     Attempts to restore a locally stored session.
     */
    public static func savedSession() -> MyAppSession? {

        do {

            let keychainData = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount(userAccount: MyAppSession.MyAppKeychainAccount)
            if let accessToken = keychainData?[MyAppSession.accessTokenKeychainKey] as? String,
                let refreshToken = keychainData?[MyAppSession.refreshTokenKeychainKey] as? String {

                return MyAppSession(accessToken: accessToken, refreshToken: refreshToken)

            }

            else if !UIApplication.shared.isProtectedDataAvailable {                    
                return nil
            }

            else {                    
                return nil
            }
        }
    }

    init?(accessToken: String, refreshToken: String) {

        // Save credentials to the keychain.
        do {

            try Locksmith.updateData(
                data: [MyAppSession.accessTokenKeychainKey: accessToken as AnyObject, MyAppSession.refreshTokenKeychainKey: refreshToken as AnyObject],
                forUserAccount: MyAppSession.MyAppKeychainAccount)

            isValid = true

        }
        catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There has been some time past on this question but I wanted to write a possible answer anyway. We have recently realized that some of user data is saved into Keychain with access level of `whenUnlock` instead of `afterFirstUnlock`.

Since it is not possible to change access level of previously saved data with less secure access level. The solution we found was removing the old user data, and re-save it with proper access level on app launch.

When keychain access error occurs for a data (due to password protection etc.), related user can be pinned and its data can be re-written on next app launch.